# Notifying java object from C/C++ code?

Tags: java, c++, c, multithreading, java-native-interface

I am wondering is it possible to notify( `notify()` ) a java object with native code?

For example let's say we have a thread in java which is waiting for a signal as below.

```
void _do_something() throws Exception{
   synchronized(__lock_){
      __lock_.wait();
   }
}
```

Then is it possible to notify the `__lock_` object from a native code?!
Should I pass the `__lock_` object to the c code? so how and how C code call the `notify()` method.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried calling "notify" like any other java method?

Comment: please add your c++ code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very doable from native code. You need to use JNI though...

> Then is it possible to notify the _*lock* object from a native code?!

Sure, as long as your native code has a handle to the _*lock* object, all you have to do is to synchronize and call notify on it (like you would call any other java object from native code).

> Should I pass the _*lock* object to the c code?

Yes. Both because you need it when you call the CallVoidMethod() JNI function to call notify() but also because you need to enter/exit Monitor of that object (the JNI equivalent way of saying "synchronized(_*lock*)"

> so how and how C code call the notify() method

First you need to understand the basics of mapping your native code to something you can call from java. Then you need to understand how to call back into java from that native code and when you understand that, it is all a matter of learning how to use MonitorEnter, CallVoidMethod and MonitorExit.

Unfortunately, JNI sometimes seems to be designed to keep people away. When you're new at it, it is kind of hard to do proper debugging. I would recommend to start small to get a grip of it and wait with the real stuff until you understand the basics.

My best advice with JNI is to stick to the rules (at least in the beginning), check exceptions after every call (and dump them to stderr or something when you get them) and run your java with -Xcheck:jni.
There are plenty of tutorials around, I found [this one](https://thenewcircle.com/bookshelf/java_fundamentals_tutorial/_java_native_interface_jni.html) in the top10-list when I googled, it seems ok.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks dude, and one more question, should I synchronize(synchronized block) the `__lock_`(mutex) in c/c++ code too?! if yes how? is there any certain method should I call? or it's jusu like calling another method without synchronization?

Comment: As I said, the JNI equivalent way of doing synchronized() is to call MonitorEnter/MonitorExit on the object (Enter for the start of the block and Exit when you leave the block). Surrounding the call to notify with that is the same as "synchronized(__lock_) {__lock_.notify();}"
Docs are here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5256